# AsyncTask Class Showing Null Pointer Exception in onProgressUpdate Method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am a beginner in android. I am trying to control a progressbar with AsyncTask in a class that extends android's inbuilt messenger class. I am getting an Exception but, can't understand the fault in my code.

```
public class MyMessenger extends Service {

private ProgressDialog downloadProgressDialog;
static final int v1=1,v2=2;
ProgressBar bar;
class MyHandler extends Handler
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case v1:

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "message = 1 in handler of messenger", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case v2:
            new sync().execute();
                        break;

        }
    }
}
Messenger messenger=new Messenger(new MyHandler());
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "binding...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return messenger.getBinder();

}
public class sync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
{
    int progress=0;
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        downloadProgressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (progress<100) {
            progress++;
            publishProgress(progress);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        downloadProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        downloadProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file...");
        downloadProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        downloadProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        downloadProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        downloadProgressDialog.show();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are unable to findViewById in service , do the same in your activity that starts the service and make bar as a public static variable.bar is null because you have not initialsed it by findViewById

```
public static ProgressBar bar =  (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);//in activity
```

Code in async task

```
//async task
     @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
          if(!MyActivityName.bar=null)

             MyActivityName.bar.setProgress(values[0]);
             super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        }
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Your answer has been accepted. Right now, I am just trying to implement it using ProgressDialog. And thanks again for your help. It really solved my problem for ProgressBar.

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize `bar`, so it is null when you use it at `bar.setProgress(values[0])`.

Comment: how do I initialize the bar in a service. findViewById() is not accessible there.

Answer (score 1):

because you didn't initialize your progress bar. initialize like below:

```
bar =  (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
```

EDIT:

Then you have to use Progressdialog rather than progress bar like below:

```
private ProgressDialog downloadProgressDialog;

protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

       downloadProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            downloadProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file...");
            downloadProgressDialog.setMax(100);
            downloadProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            downloadProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            downloadProgressDialog.show();
    }
```

and then use dialog object in your progressupdate method.

EDIT:

Via Binder you can send callbacks to your Activity, which means that you can update UI like progress dialog.

```
Add according method to your Binder (let's name it onProgress)
From your AsyncTask call method of this Binder
In order to know about progress updates consider using Observer pattern (in other words - your Activity should listen for updates of your Binder, or more specifically - of calling Binder.onProgress method)
```

Comment: I tried it but, findViewById() method is not accessible there. because it's a service. I even tried it with getApplicationContext() but, all my efforts in vain. could you please suggest me the solution to it.

Comment: Me getting an exception in the line -- downloadProgressDialog.show();
EXCEPTION:
E/AndroidRuntime(1600): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: pass activity class as context in progressdialog.

Comment: put this keyword rather than context in progressdialog.

Comment: with this keyword it gives me this errer--
The constructor ProgressDialog(MyMessenger.sync) is undefined

Comment: i have edited the code in the question with the code of downloadProgressDialog. please refer for the edited code there.

Comment: i tried it. but, it gives me an error stating "The constructor ProgressDialog(MyMessenger.sync) is undefined"

Comment: then pass your activity name in it. and must be import in service class.

Comment: By import, do you mean -- Activity activity=new MyActivity(); and then refer this activity over there?

Comment: sorry, i already give you so many information in my last edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can not to show progress dialog , You have extend service class that is used to run thread in background. just use only doinbackground() method, remove progress dialog method
.